# layoutSubviews - called infinitely on tap on custom UITableViewCell - only in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've been juggling with this issue - only for iOS 6, when I tap on my custom cell in my table view, layoutSubviews of my custom cell class goes in infinite loop. Surprisingly, the same custom cell class works fine in my another view controller. I know layoutSubviews gets called for any cell content frame change but I am unable to figure out the root cause here.

Any clue would really help.

PS: When I run by putting breakpoint, it work all fine.

Comment: do you use autolayout?

Comment: @JulianKról - No; I am not using auto layout here.

Comment: so what do you change on a tap action? maybe some code to talk technically not only using imagination :P

Comment: Nothing - thats what. In fact I am not implementing didSelectRow as I don't need to do any thing. I could not disable user interactions on cell as I am providing swipe to delete feature.

Comment: no code no help. I can only guessing. mentioning that setting breakpoints helps only gives me some clue that maybe it is some race condition going on but as i said no code no better advice

Comment: call to super is made after or before your code ?

Comment: do you have tableindextitles implemented?

Comment: No. I do not have tableindextitles.